# Autolayout constraints issue on 5S 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, xcode6.1

I am trying to implement `Auto Layout` with simple two components on a story board. I have added constraints successfully.

They are working fine on iOS 8.1 simulator (5s), here is screenshot:
[image]

But same constraints are not working on iOS7.1 simulator (5s), here is screenshot:
[image]
Here are the constraints added:
[image: Here are the constraints added:]

I couldn't figure why on same simulator for different iOS, constraints are failing. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Click into the red arrow on the upper-right of your second screenshot and fix constraints error.

Comment: Did that still same issue.

Comment: Add width, height and Top spacing,Bottom spacing to superview..for image..

Comment: @Vidhyanand900: superview for image is "View" in my case, I couldn't set Top Spacing, Bottom Spacing for this view. Did I understand your comment correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the following constraint

**For Screen1:**

1. Center X to the superView
2. Center Y to the superView

**For Label :**

1. Top Space to the Screen1
2. Leading space to Superview

That's all

Answer (score 0):

U need to set Below constraints like below

select image.

Editor-->Pin-->Width

Editor-->Pin-->Height

Editor-->Pin-->Top spacing to superview

Editor-->Pin-->Bottom spacing to superview.

For fixing constraints error..U need to click on yellow arrow on top of the view.

Click on Reset to suggested constraints-->Ok.

Through Editor

Editor-->Resolve Autolayout Issues--> Reset to suggested constraints.

Else Have added below code at view Did Load

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Hope it helps you..!